# How to deal with supervisor giving wrong information?

Tags: united-states, conflict, lying

I have a supervisor who keeps giving me incorrect information. This is a foreigner who has been hiring others from her home country whenever a job opens. Now, most of my co-workers are foreigners. I think her goal is to get rid of me.

Here are some examples:

- She assigned me a critical task to complete at home, giving me a deadline of Wednesday, but telling everyone else my deadline was Tuesday.
- When I ask for information about the requirements are for some work, she says she doesn't know, or is vague, so I don't know how to do the work. But when talking to others on the team, she is specific and others assume I get the same information.

How can I protect myself in such a situation?

Comment: If it is your manager / supervisor document everything (stating you need specific information with date / time (emails)) and start looking for a new job.  Considering she continues to hire "her own" and doesn't want to help you means you will have a losing battle.

Comment: Can you add a location tag?

Answer (score 6):

> How can I protect myself in such a situation?

It is time for a new job, **get the heck out of there ASAP.**

Update your resume with the latest information, start applying for new openings as soon as possible, and don't look back at that place.  In the meantime, do your best to keep your head down and stay off your manager's radar.

You have mentioned several **HUGE red flags** already which should make you feel as though the ax is about to fall.

Answer (score 4):

Call her out on the inconsistencies.

> I’m sorry, you told me the deadline for this work was Wednesday, but everyone else says it’s Tuesday. Which one is it?

If they’re trying to get rid of you, there’s nothing lost doing this. There’s also a possibility that there’s genuine misunderstanding, so this is a way of getting that cleared up.

In the meantime, document any requests you get so you can refer back to what you’ve been told.

Documentation of inconsistencies can be used as defence if you’re subject to unfair dismissal.

Comment: For documentation purposes, communicate via email as much as possible, send confirmation emails for everything else.

Comment: And if team members are kind enough to forward the conflicting information that they have, so much the better.

Comment: ... and if you have enough documentation, consider taking it to her boss.

Comment: Got to be careful with that one cuz this may be her executing her boss's plan.

Comment: Do you mean "documentation of inconsistencies"?